# before(:each) for all tests except one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

This is part of my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

 config.before(:each) do
  login(email, password)
  visit root_url
 end

end
```

that I need in all of my (20+) tests except one.

Is there a way to avoid that **single test** to execute the `before hook`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can add metadata to tests that do not need to login, then evaluate that metadata in your `before` hook.

For example, two tests in the same file. One needs to login and one does not.

```
# foo_spec.rb
describe Foo do
  describe "#bar" do
    it "needs to log in" do
      expect(1).to eq 1
    end
  end
  describe "#baz" do
    it "needs to not log in", :logged_out do
      expect(1).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

So we added metadata to our `it` block. Next, we configure the `before` hook to evaluate the example's metadata.

```
config.before(:each) do |test|
  login(email, password) unless test.metadata[:logged_out]
  visit root_url
end
```

Now, each test will `visit root_url` but only the ones not tagged with `:logged_out` will call `login`.

RSpec calls these metadata based hooks filters. You can learn a bit more about them [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters#filter-%60before%28:example%29%60-hooks-using-arbitrary-metadata).

Answer (score 6):

Putting this kind of code into spec helper seems a bit odd. Feature specs is all you have? No unit tests? Even if it's the former, copy that code into individual specs that need it. If they're all in the same file, you can use contexts to prevent some duplication.

```
RSpec.describe 'something' do
  context 'specs with login' do
    before do 
      login(email, password)
      visit root_url
    end

    it { ... }
  end

  context 'specs without login' do
    it { ... }
  end
end
```

Global rspec config in spec_helper.rb is meant for other things. Ones that make sense for **each and every** spec. Like, for example, cleaning a database.

```
config.before :each do 
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Comment: I have lots of specs (1_spec.rb, 2_spec.rb, 3_spec.rb etc...) that's why I put the login and visit in my spec_helper, as I need them in all of the tests. except one...

Comment: @fabersky: in other words, you don't need them in __each__ spec? Therefore can't use the spec_helper.

Comment: if i put the `before do` with some different action in the spec where I don't need the login and visit, will rspec execute the before that is in my spec_helper or the one that is in the spec i'm running?

Comment: I have 22 specs, i need them in 21 of them

Comment: @fabersky: it will run both.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's 1 or 10 which don't need it, sadly it doesn't change the fact that any code in spec_helper.rb is going to apply to all. Another option from the answer above is to create a spec_login.rb file with that before hook code, then require it within the test files which need it.

*spec/spec_login.rb*

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

 config.before(:each) do
  login(email, password)
  visit root_url
 end

end
```

*spec/1_spec.rb (needs login)*

```
require 'spec_login'

describe 'BlahBlah' do

end
```

*spec/2_spec.rb (no login)*

```
describe 'BlahBlah' do

end
```

Comment: This thing with `spec_login.rb` won't work, I'm afraid. It makes global change (installs the global before hook, which will not clear after this file is run).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the check inside `spec_helper's config.before(:each) block` 
based on the `test.metadata[:described_class] or [:example_group]`.

It has tons of information about the current context so it might be a bit more straightforward to do the filtering from inside the block instead of changing the specs individually.